# EF how to include subobject to query

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, orm

I have two tables: Users and Tokens like below.

[image]

Now I write query using EF, it take Token object, but subobject User inside Token object is null. How should I modify my query to get Token with User object?

```
using (var db = new AccountDbContext())
{
    Token tok = db.Tokens
       .FirstOrDefault(p => tokenValue == p.Value) == 0);

    if (tok.User == null)
    {
        //I'm there, but I 100% of sure thata this relation exists
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Comment: your returned object should have the `user` object like `tokenObj.User`! if the relationship exists

Comment: @sarwar026: Please look at my updated code.

Comment: I see. But don't understand why it is `null` if there is a relation!

Comment: You may see the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065177/entity-framework-eager-load-two-many-to-many-relationships question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity framework doesn't automatically load all the related objects out of the database - this could be very expensive if there were many tables with lots of relations.  You either need to tell EF to load the associated `User` in your query (this is called Eager Loading), or you need to enable Lazy Loading so that EF will load it when it is first accessed.  (See the MSDN article [Loading Related Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) for more details.

Here's an example of Eager Loading (not thoroughly tested, since I don't have your model):

```
using (var db = new AccountDbContext())
{
    Token tok = db.Tokens.Include(n => n.User)
       .FirstOrDefault(p => tokenValue == p.Value) == 0);
}
```